# Can I enter the UK before my student visa as a Canadian citizen?

Tags: uk, canada, study, student-visas

I am a Canadian citizen. I've been living with my English partner for the last two years in Canada and I have officially been accepted to an English University for a 1 year masters degree starting September 2021. I will be applying for a Tier 4 UK study visa, but I was hoping to move to the UK in July 2021 to stay with my partner's family for around 60 days before school starts. The student visa says that you are only allowed to enter the UK a month before your studies start, but I know that Canadian citizens don't need a visa to enter the UK as a tourist/visitor. Will I be okay to go in July and stay in the UK for the duration of my student visa afterwards? Thank you so much in advance for your help!

Comment: Are you prepared to leave the UK (to somewhere outside the common travel area) and re-enter sometime in the 30 days before the start of your program?

Comment: No, I was hoping to show my student visa upon entry as a visitor. Would I really have to re-enter if I'm legally allowed to be in the UK during both periods of time (visitor and student)?

Comment: I think you would, yes.  People admitted as visitors are explicitly prohibited from switching to a different status.  A day trip to the continent by ferry or train would suffice.  The reason I'm not answering is because I don't know how likely it would be to cause problems with the immigration officer.

Comment: Okay great, thank you so much for your time!!! I really appreciate it.